# Windows 8 remote desktop - can I see what the remote user sees?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 8 computer on my test bench connected to a test set with a dedicated incoming internet line.  By using remote desktop, I allow it to be used by people in India to remotely control the test set.  When they remotely log in to my computer on my test bench, the monitor on my test bench switches to the login screen showing that they are logged in.  Is there a setting so that I can see the same screen that they see, so I can watch what they are doing, rather than just seeing the login screen?

Answer (score 3):

Not with RDP. You'll need to use something like TeamViewer, LogMeIn, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Remote desktop only allows one user logged in and viewing the screen, as far as I know.

You would have to use a screen-sharing service such as TeamViewer or Windows Remote Assistance, or set up a VNC server on your computer using something like RealVNC.

Answer (score 0):

In 2012R2, there is an old feature that has been reintegrated - it is called Shadow. It allows you to "shadow" a session (see what the user sees) even without the user consent (you have to be admin and you need an RDS deployment). More details here: http://www.petri.co.il/shadow-remote-desktop-session-in-windows-server-2012-r2.htm - I couldn't find the official MSDN page, but I am sure if you search for enough time, you will.

Otherwise, things like TeamViewer and RealVNC work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Things like [Radmin](http://www.radmin.com) allow you to connect to the same session and see what remote users see, troubleshoot them and communicate with them.